# Webpack css change image path after build

Tags: javascript, css, build, webpack

In development, i have this structure:

```
- dist - contain the css bundle
- sass - style.scss
- js
- img
- index.html
```

In production, i have this structure:

```
- img
- some-hash.js
- some-hase.css
- index.html
```

So in development my image url should be relative to the img folder like this:

```
background: url('../img/logo.jpg');
```

But in production it should be like this:

```
background: url('img/logo.jpg');
```

How we solve this problem with webpack or in general?

Answer (score 1):

You need have publicPath in webpack config.

[webpack-howto](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto)

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    path: './build', // This is where images AND js will go
    publicPath: 'http://mycdn.com/', // This is used to generate URLs to e.g. images or publicPath: '/'
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader' }, // use ! to chain loaders
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' } // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: If I only want to change images' publicPath instead all static file like js css files, how should I do?